# Is this good practice for a python while loop?

Tags: python

This seems a bit too ugly to be particularly pythonic, but I can't find anything in PEP8 that tells me otherwise. Assume all statements are defined and work in the obvious way.

```
def myfunction():
    data = None
    results = 1
    while results >0:
        data = make_lots_of_data_function(next_page)
        for i in data:
            do_something_with_i
            ...
        update(next_page)
        results = data['num_results']
```

I just don't like this `result = 1` business. Just think there's a better way of doing this. Basically the algorithm is:

- Get some data.
- Do something with it.
- Get more data.
- Stop when data runs out.

Comment: I don't see anything bad here..

Comment: Python doesn't support the `do`/`while` construct of C and friends... you could do something like `done = False; while not done:...`

Comment: IMHO I find more readable: while True: [...] if data['num_results'] == 0: break

Comment: `break` doesn't help to read the code I'd say. The loop says: "Hey, i'm never going to stop", but somewhere else in the code, you are exiting the loop, which can be tricky to debug.

Comment: @David Boshton: Since you seem to care about the PEP8, you could comply to it on this code: spaces around `=`, and don't forget the colon on the function definition

Comment: Yes, good point. @Paco.

Comment: @KillianDS; I've included as many details as necessary. Comment if you want more.

Comment: Ah, the eternal to while True or not to while True question.  It's just personal preference, in python - and in general.  The only time it matters is if your employer has a strict style manual.

Comment: MIne has PEP8 and his (usually very good) opinion.

Comment: @robert_x44, that's very true

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunction():
    data = {'num_results': 1}
    while data['num_results']:
        data = make_lots_of_data_function(next_page)
        for i in data:
            do_something_with_i
            ...
        update(next_page)
```

at least gets rid of the results variable